# Can not access to my apache server remotely

Tags: apache-2.2

I have bought a VPS server, setted the apache server. But I could only access the webpage from local, [image]

[image]

I thought maybe the server did not recieveing access from outside.

I tried Firefox, but the access_log shows nothing accessed. But telnet http://www.59lt.com 80
and type nonsence code, I recieved following error:
[image]

and the access_log under /etc/httpd/logs also caught the acess, 
[image]

This proved that the server do access request from outside, so why it ignore the normal request from Firefox, but choosed to recieving request from telnet?

Thanks.

PS: I'm using CentOS + yum installed apache(just now installed).

Comment: I can access your system from the UK I get the `a test this is for test` message.

Comment: Can you access other websites from your firefox? You may have an invalid proxy settings in your browser!

Comment: Thanks to all of you, esp will. The problem is caused by the authentication system of the VPS host company. And actually I have used ipconfig /flushdns to flush the dns cache. Now the problme is setted.

Answer (score 3):

The most likley cause of this problem is that you have a cached DNS entry for this domain name. On your screenshot above it appears that you have telnet'ed to 118.123.13.46 rather than www.59lt.com which would explain why it is working. This would happen if you have updated the DNS entry for this domain name recently as it can sometime take days (usually 24 hours) for the change to propgate depending on the configuration of the zone file for your domain.

One way to test this would be run a command line (start > run > cmd.exe) and then type: ping www.59lt.com. If the IP show does not match 118.123.13.46 then a stale DNS entry is the problem and it will clear itself when the TTL of the domain expires. 
If this is the case then you can add an entry to your hosts file to overide the DNS entry untill it updates see [here](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/windows-7-hosts-file/) for instructions.

If this still doesnt not work please post the error message you are getting in firefox.